# C# Split String before the first number

Tags: c#, split

I have some String form the database for example:

```
Example123456.csv
```

Now i want to split the string here:

```
Example 123456 .csv
```

The finish outprint should be:

```
123456
```

Is this possible?

Comment: So, do you wanna get _only_ digits in your string? Do you have a pattern or something?

Comment: Yes its possible, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the following Regex To extract no from your string

```
string input ="Example123456.csv";
input = Regex.Replace(input, "[^0-9]+", string.Empty);
```

the output will be 123456

Answer (score 0):

Use RegEx:

```
string input = "Example123456.csv";
var result = Regex.Match(input, @"\D+(?<num>\d+)\.\w+").Groups["num"].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) (check it out [here](https://regex101.com/r/uM1eI8/1)) to extract your number as a string:

```
string myString = "Example123456.csv";
result = Regex.Match(myString, @"\d+").Value; // now result is "123456"
```

and then if you want your result as an integer use:

```
result = Int32.Parse(result); // now result is 123456
```